# Create an heatmap using pupil lab hmd package

Tags: unity-game-engine, heatmap, virtual-reality, eye-tracking

My goal is to generate and export spherical videos or still images with heatmaps generated from gaze postions. I use an htc vive, unity software and pupil hardware (https://pupil-labs.com/vr-ar/)

These are the sites where is explained how to do this:

https://github.com/pupil-labs/hmd-eyes

https://github.com/pupil-labs/hmd-eyes/blob/master/Developer.md

So, i download the package *pupil.import.package.vr.v 0.61.unitypackage* (https://github.com/pupil-labs/hmd-eyes/releases/tag/v0.61)
I import it on unity, so i have three folder pupil_plugin, market scene demo and streamingAssets (import from the source code, i dont find inside the package and it's necessary to record the video).

In order to understand how this package works, before to make my project on unity, I use the scenes demo given in the package to make an heatmap: *heatmap demo and market with heatmap.*

First, I set up the building setting as described in the developer page and I insert *heatmap demo scene and market with heatmap scene* in scene build.

After, I load in the hierarchy of unity the *heatmap demo scene* and I change the recording path inside pupilgazetracker (inside pupil manager).

Finally, I build an exe.

I play the exe, it managed to make the connection with pupil capture, i can do a successful calibration and after I can record a video pressing h to obtain where i am looking at.

When i play the recordered video, i see only the 3d and I can't see the heatmap overlayed.

There aren't any errors in console.

I also try to change the mode in heatmap script into highlight but when i play the video i see a white video.

Could you help me?